# How to log user in to Gnome Desktop from remote ssh terminal?

Tags: linux, gnome, centos

I'm using CentOS 5.5 with Gnome Desktop Enironment.
By default, after system boot i get Gnome's login screen. Independently, I can log in through SSH and execute commands.

Is there any command line tool, that would log user in to GNOME ?

I know, there is AutomaticLogin feature in GNOME `[daemon]` section in  `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`  file , but I don't want to use it. I would like to be able do it "on demand" from SSH command line.

Comment: Not really much help here as I use KDE. But I do the same thing you're trying with kdmctl. There might be an analog for it in gnome, but I couldn't really say.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to be able to use X apps on your side of the ssh connection or log someone on the remote side into your account?

Answer (score 1):

From your ssh session, have you tried to launch `gnome-session`?
You just need an X-server running on your client computer.

Comment: Doesn't work. Produces error `"(gnome-session:3758): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: "`. I've also tried running scripts located in `/etc/gdm/` - no success as well.

Comment: Are you running `ssh` with `-X` or the `ForwardX11` option set to `Yes`? It sounds like X forwarding isn't happening.